# "this" getting lost while dealing with angular leaflet click events

Tags: angular, rest, leaflet

Once I capture the click event on a leaflet marker and go to the associated function, I loose this for current context.

Marker create code:

> const marker = L.marker([lon, lat], c).addEventListener("click", this.onClickRainFall).addTo(map);

and associated function is:

```
private onClickRainFall(e){
var sourceUrl2 = "a.b.c.d/" + e.sourceTarget.options.properties.abc;
this.getData(sourceUrl2);
```

}

Here when I try to access this.getData, at runtime I get error that "ERROR TypeError: this.getData is not a function"

Function definition for getData is:

```
public getData(sourceUrl){
console.log('I  am called');
this.dataService.getData(sourceUrl).subscribe(data => {
  this.myData = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(this.myData);
});
```

}

Please let me know how to solve it and get the reference of this properly.

Comment: Try using `.bind(this)` like `addEventListener("click", this.onClickRainFall.bind(this))`. There are a lot of simular questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Hi yurzui: I tried this but it says Cannot read properly  getdata of undefined. I didn't get a question like this. Please have a look once.

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assign `this` to another variable before triggering the `eventListener` then use the new variable instead of `this`.

Example:

```
let that = this;
const marker = L.marker([lon, lat], c).addEventListener("click", function() {
    var sourceUrl2 = "a.b.c.d/" + e.sourceTarget.options.properties.abc; that.getData(sourceUrl2);
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the context to the associated function.

```
this.onClickRainFall.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit simpler option

```
const marker = L.marker([lon, lat], c).addEventListener("click", (e) => this.onClickRainFall(e)).addTo(map);
```

With `this` becoming an upvalue